# AngularJS $resource - Set custom header with username/password?

Tags: angularjs, header, resources

I want to create a new REST method for my login system, where I supply user credentials in a custom header. How can I do it in with AngularJS/ng-resource? I've tried the below code but the problem is when i try to get the username/password from the forms($scope.vm.username). This gives me 'undefined' if I do it it in the headers setup.

```
angular.module('BkSystemApp.controllers', ['ngResource'])

.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $location, $resource){
    //init
    $scope.vm = {};

    function getUserCredentials(){
        return ($scope.vm.username + ':' + $scope.vm.password)
    }

    //resources
    var Authentication = $resource('/users/authentication',{},{
        login:{
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            headers: {'Authentication':btoa(getUserCredentials())}
        }
    });

    //HTTP methods
    $scope.login = function(){
        Authentication.login(function(data){

        });     
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the `$resource` `.login` method compute the header string at method invocation time, the header configuation needs to have a header property with a value which is a function declaration, not a function invocation.

```
 //resources
var Authentication = $resource('/users/authentication',{},{
    login:{
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false,
        //USE function declaration
        headers: {
           'Authentication': 
                function () {
                    return btoa(getUserCredentials())
                }
        }
        //NOT function invocation
        //headers: {'Authentication':btoa(getUserCredentials())}
    }
});
```

This way the `Authentication` value will be computed each time the `login` method gets invoked.

NOTE: It is not wise to send username and password in the header of an XHR GET request.

Comment: Solution worked, but I guess I will send the username and password in a POST body instead.